# Server Mail log - continuously being spammed with SMTP sessions

Tags: linux, ssh, email, smtp

my server is being continuously bombarded with these smtp sessions. I checked through SSH:

```
tail -f /usr/local/psa/var/log/maillog
```

and I'm getting these continuosly:

```
Apr 12 16:48:21 891326-db2 postfix/smtpd[46245]: warning: unknown[xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]: SASL LOGIN authentication failed: encryption needed to use mechanism
Apr 12 16:48:21 891326-db2 postfix/smtpd[47413]: connect from unknown[000.000.000.000]
Apr 12 16:48:21 891326-db2 postfix/smtpd[46245]: lost connection after AUTH from unknown[xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]
Apr 12 16:48:21 891326-db2 postfix/smtpd[46245]: disconnect from unknown[xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]
Apr 12 16:48:21 891326-db2 postfix/smtpd[47413]: warning: unknown[000.000.000.000]: SASL LOGIN authentication failed: encryption needed to use mechanism
Apr 12 16:48:21 891326-db2 postfix/smtpd[47413]: lost connection after AUTH from unknown[000.000.000.000]
Apr 12 16:48:21 891326-db2 postfix/smtpd[47413]: disconnect from unknown[000.000.000.000]
Apr 12 16:48:21 891326-db2 postfix/smtpd[46245]: connect from unknown[xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]
Apr 12 16:48:21 891326-db2 postfix/smtpd[46245]: warning: unknown[xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]: SASL LOGIN authentication failed: encryption needed to use mechanism
Apr 12 16:48:21 891326-db2 postfix/smtpd[46245]: lost connection after AUTH from unknown[xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]
Apr 12 16:48:21 891326-db2 postfix/smtpd[46245]: disconnect from unknown[xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]
Apr 12 16:48:21 891326-db2 postfix/smtpd[47413]: connect from unknown[xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]
Apr 12 16:48:21 891326-db2 postfix/smtpd[47413]: warning: unknown[xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]: SASL LOGIN authentication failed: encryption needed to use mechanism
Apr 12 16:48:21 891326-db2 postfix/smtpd[47413]: lost connection after AUTH from unknown[xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]
Apr 12 16:48:21 891326-db2 postfix/smtpd[47413]: disconnect from unknown[xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]

Apr 12 17:03:04 891326-db2 postfix/smtp[1148]: connect to example.com[93.184.216.34]:25: Connection timed out
Apr 12 17:03:04 891326-db2 postfix/smtp[1148]: connect to example.com[2606:2800:220:1:248:1893:25c8:1946]:25: Network is unreachable
Apr 12 17:03:04 891326-db2 postfix/smtp[1148]: 12E2620617BE: to=<hackyou@example.com>, relay=none, delay=265075, delays=265045/0.02/30/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to example.com[2606:2800:220:1:248:1893:25c8:1946]:25: Network is unreachable)
Apr 12 17:03:04 891326-db2 postfix/smtp[1154]: connect to example.com[93.184.216.34]:25: Connection timed out
Apr 12 17:03:04 891326-db2 postfix/smtp[1154]: connect to example.com[2606:2800:220:1:248:1893:25c8:1946]:25: Network is unreachable
Apr 12 17:03:04 891326-db2 postfix/smtp[1154]: 17C632062FAB: to=<hackyou@example.com>, relay=none, delay=155962, delays=155932/0.04/30/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to example.com[2606:2800:220:1:248:1893:25c8:1946]:25: Network is unreachable)
Apr 12 17:03:04 891326-db2 postfix/smtp[1153]: connect to example.com[93.184.216.34]:25: Connection timed out
Apr 12 17:03:04 891326-db2 postfix/smtp[1153]: connect to example.com[2606:2800:220:1:248:1893:25c8:1946]:25: Network is unreachable
Apr 12 17:03:04 891326-db2 postfix/smtp[1153]: 1FF3820617F9: to=<hackyou@example.com>, relay=none, delay=264998, delays=264968/0.03/30/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to example.com[2606:2800:220:1:248:1893:25c8:1946]:25: Network is unreachable)
Apr 12 17:03:04 891326-db2 postfix/smtp[1151]: connect to example.com[93.184.216.34]:25: Connection timed out
Apr 12 17:03:04 891326-db2 postfix/smtp[1151]: connect to example.com[2606:2800:220:1:248:1893:25c8:1946]:25: Network is unreachable
Apr 12 17:03:04 891326-db2 postfix/smtp[1151]: 18756206303B: to=<hackyou@example.com>, relay=none, delay=155848, delays=155818/0.02/30/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to example.com[2606:2800:220:1:248:1893:25c8:1946]:25: Network is unreachable)
Apr 12 17:03:04 891326-db2 postfix/error[1160]: 1400220630A7: to=<hackyou@example.com>, relay=none, delay=155758, delays=155728/30/0/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (delivery temporarily suspended: connect to example.com[2606:2800:220:1:248:1893:25c8:1946]:25: Network is unreachable)
```

I've already blocked the IPs, but new IPs keep appearing after I block it. Any idea how these sessions are being created or solutions for this? A bit out of ideas...

Comment: `SASL LOGIN authentication failed` are typically bots that attempt to do brute force password guessing by means of the SMTP authentication channel. That has become another part of the internet background noise, unfortunately

Comment: `12E2620617BE: to=<hackyou@example.com>` did you send this?

Comment: @TorinCarey nope. I didnt send that. That's what is showing up on the log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to use log scanning software (`sec.pl`, `fail2ban`) that block the IP addresses (temporarily, usually) after X many events (possibly as low as 1 if the server is not used for `SMTP AUTH`, higher if there may be users flailing at their keyboards) which in turn will help cut down on the log spam.

For `sec.pl` I blacklist them, and other scripts handle removing the blacklist entries after some time (with increased time to removal if the remote IP persists in being a log spammer):

```
type=SingleWithThreshold
ptype=RegExp
pattern=postfix/smtpd\[\d+\]: lost connection after AUTH from [^\[]+\[([^\]]+)
desc=smtp AUTH spam from $1
action=shellcmd /root/bin/blacklistip $1
window=300
thresh=3
```

The `blacklistip` script mostly just calls `iptables` or `ip6tables` as appropriate and adds the IP to a chain that is not permitted to connect.

Comment: Yea, I used fail2ban. But everytime I add 1 IP a new one appears.. consistently getting bombarded by these smtp sessions

Comment: so a) ban them longer b) ignore the logs c) look for subnets that can be blacklisted (e.g. cloud providers) as they don't do business you ...